# Compare two arrays of player scores to see who has gone up/down in the list

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, indexing

I have two arrays which are taken in different time periods. How to check what player has gone up/down in the list with the inclusion of marking a new player also as going up?

P.S. - Arrays are already sorted according to the score.

```
pastData:[
  
    {
    playerName:'John Doe',
    score:50
    },
    {
    playerName:'Jane Doe',
    score:40
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Appleseed',
    score:30
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Walker',
    score:20
    },
  ]

presentData:[

    {
    playerName:'Jane Doe',
    score:80
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Doe',
    score:60
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Appleseed',
    score:40
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Mayer',
    score:30
    },
  ]
```

I need to check the index changes comparing the two arrays and get an output like following.

```
   presentData:[

    {
    playerName:'Jane Doe',
    score:80,
    position:'up'
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Doe',
    score:60,
    position:'down'
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Appleseed',
    score:40,
    position:'same'
    },
    {
    playerName:'John Mayer',
    score:30,
    position:'up'
    },
  ]
```

I'm trying as below but can't seem to find a solution for the new player usecase.

```
let status=[] //this array will include the changes 
which I can use later to update the presentData array 
with a "position:'up/down/same'" key-value pairs.

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 

  for(let j=0; j<4; j++) {

   if(Object.values(pastData)[i].id==Object.values(presentData)[j].id){
     if(i==j){
      status.push('same')

     }
     if(i<j){
      status.push('down')

      }
     if(i>j){
       status.push('up')
     }
   }

  }

  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) out of the `pastData` array which maps the `playerName` to their `index`.
2. Iterate over the `presentData` array and using the map calculate the position for every player.

```js
const pastData = [
  { playerName: "John Doe", score: 50 },
  { playerName: "Jane Doe", score: 40 },
  { playerName: "John Appleseed", score: 30 },
  { playerName: "John Walker", score: 20 },
];

const presentData = [
  { playerName: "Jane Doe", score: 80 },
  { playerName: "John Doe", score: 60 },
  { playerName: "John Appleseed", score: 40 },
  { playerName: "John Mayer", score: 30 },
];

const pastDataMap = new Map(pastData.map((d, i) => [d.playerName, i]));

const status = presentData.map((d, i) => {
  const pastIndex = pastDataMap.get(d.playerName);
  return {
    ...d,
    position:
      pastIndex === undefined || i < pastIndex
        ? "up"
        : i > pastIndex
        ? "down"
        : "same",
  };
});

console.log(status);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: thanks for the solution but there are edge cases where a player's score would not change and still make him go down on the list. In your example it's assumed that the present score of John Doe has been reduced to 20 from 80.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're saying, can you give an example? And John Doe's score initially is 50 and is reduce to 20, so the position is "down", isn't it correct?

Comment: If you consider that as a single case, yes. But in the original example it goes to 60 from 50. So for the original example values, using your method gives an output of up,up,up,up.

Comment: 60 from 50 is "up" only and all other scores are also greater than their past values, so it's up for all of those? What's the confusion here?

Comment: The confusion is that the crucial part which is the original dataset is not being tested here. I have also given the desired output. The question is to check who has gone up/down in the list not whose score has been increased. "Compare two arrays of player scores to see who has gone up/down in the list"

Comment: @SKR123 Okay, now I get you! I've updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: You have my up vote too. Now reading after reading all the comments and the solution finally i understand

Comment: thank you both! Highly appreciate the discussion!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `pastDataScoreHash` with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and create a `result` array with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) adding `position` property to each players and getting it's value by comparing the `pastDataScoreHash`'s past `score` with current `score`

Code:

```js
const pastData = [
  { playerName: 'John Doe', score: 50 },
  { playerName: 'Jane Doe', score: 40 },
  { playerName: 'John Appleseed', score: 30 },
  { playerName: 'John Walker', score: 20 },
]

const presentData = [
  { playerName: 'Jane Doe', score: 80 },
  { playerName: 'John Doe', score: 60 },
  { playerName: 'John Appleseed', score: 40 },
  { playerName: 'John Mayer', score: 30 },
]

const pastDataHash = pastData.reduce((a, { playerName: p }, i) => ((a[p] = i), a), {})

const getPosition = (past, current) => {
  switch (true) {
    case past == current:
      return 'same'
    case past == undefined || past > current:
      return 'up'
    default:
      return 'down'
  }
}

const result = presentData.map((p, i) => ({
  ...p,
  position: getPosition(pastDataHash[p.playerName], i),
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401269/compare-two-arrays-of-player-scores-to-see-who-has-gone-up-down-in-the-list#
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Do you have an idea to solve the edge case of a new player? Since John Mayer wasn't in the initial array he should be marked as up.

Comment: sorry to point out again but it gives consecutive "up"s instead of up,down,same,up.

Comment: I have made code refactor

Comment: just to point out that @SSM has made an assumption that a player's score would decrease(John Doe goes to 80 from 20) which would not happen and it will give different output as up,up,up,up for the original example.

Comment: Updated  answer with OP data

Comment: @SKR123 There's *no* assumption anywhere, you can change the dataset to whatever you like. I've just chosen a sample dataset to demonstrate all possible positions.

Comment: it's becoming a long discussion :/ there's a mismatch between the desired output i believe? Since it should be up,down,same and up instead of all up?

Comment: @SSM but it's not giving the desired output for the original dataset is what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Jane Doe: 40 -> 80, John Doe: 50 -> 60, John Appleseed: 30 -> 40, John Mayer: undefined -> 30. So all "up" only, why do you expect "up", "down", "same" and "up"?

Comment: To get the desired "output" then you should prepare a set of data for `pastData` and `presentData `. Thank you

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles umm it's already in the question? the pastData array and the presentData array?

Answer (score -2):

This is a solution about x4 faster than first one.

```
presentData.map((present,index)=> {

    const pastIndexPostion = pastData.findIndex(t => t.playerName === present.playerName)
    if(pastIndexPostion > index || pastIndexPostion===-1){
        present.position = 'up'
    }else if(pastIndexPostion === index){
        present.position = 'same'
    }else {
        present.position = 'down'
    }
    return present
})
```